# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 (RevMob)

Tags: ios, revmob

I tried deleting everything RevMob ads related in my app, i didn't know how to do it properly so i firstly deleted the framework than erased all the line of code related to RevMob but now i have this error that i can fix:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RevMobAds", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
```

I found people having the same problem (not with RevMob but similar framework) but they we're searching to add it to the project, i'm trying to REMOVE it. 
If you could tell me what to remove in order that error, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a file (probably called) AppDelegate.m, you are possibly including RevMob headers are using its objects.  If not in that file, then in a file it includes.

This error means that you had the headers at compile time to use RevMob, but you don't have the framework or library at link time (or the framework or library doesn't have the implementation of the object you are trying to use in the simulator build)

Comment: It removed the error but added another one... Now it says : `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. Any idea on how to fix that one? Tried searching the error but couldn't find anything that was related to my problem..

Comment: And no other error?  Follow this, http://docs.millennialmedia.com/iOS-SDK/iOSAddingLinkerFlag.html -- except add -v as suggested in the error